# Gluing $S^1 \times D^2$ with it's copy along $S^1 \times S^1$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology

I am studying basics of topology and the task is to prove that gluing $S^1 \times D^2$ with it's copy along $S^1 \times S^1$ results in space homeomorphic to $S^1 \times S^2$.
I came up with a following simple proof:

Let $f: S^1 \times S^1 \rightarrow S^1 \times S^1$, $f_1: S^1 \rightarrow S^1$. Then:
$$(S^1 \times D^2) \cup_{f} (S^1 \times D^2) = (S^1 \cup_{f_1} S^1) \times (D^2 \cup_{f_1} D^2) \cong S^1 \times S^2$$

Does this proof make sense? What should ideal formal proof look like?

Comment: I've stared at this for like five minutes straight and I still can't figure out what $f$ and $f_1$ are supposed to be.

Comment: @Tyrone, by that I meant equivalence relation (mapping boundary of one copy to boundary of another one). So $f$ is making $S^1 \times S^1$ equivalent for both copies, thus gluing them together, and same with $f_1$.

Comment: Ithink you should edit in some details to your question and briefly but carefully explain what these maps are supposed to be (also $S^1$ is boundaryless, so I have no idea what $S^1\cup_{f_1}S^1$ is supposed to be).

Comment: This might depend on what $f$ is. For a suitable $f$ I'm sure one can get $S^3$.

Comment: @AnginaSeng I considered functions mapping "same elements to same elements", but $S^1 \times S^2$ is not homeomorphic to $S^3$?

Comment: Certainly not: look at their fundamental groups.

Answer (score 1):

As it stands your proof doesn't really make sense, because you haven't defined $f$ or $f_1$, and as Angina Seng brings up in a comment for some choices of $f$ the quotient space is actually $S^3$. To establish more formally the result you want, prove the following:

> **Lemma:** Suppose $X = X_1 \cup_f X_2$ for some $f\colon A_1 \to A_2$ where $A_i\subset X_i$. If $Y$ is any space then $$Y\times X \cong (Y\times X_1) \cup_{id_Y\times f} (Y\times X_2)$$
> for $id_Y\times f\colon Y\times A_1 \to Y\times A_2$.

Then using this lemma you can see that $S^1\times S^2 \cong (S^1\times D^2)\cup_{id_{S^1}\times id_{S^1}}(S^1\times D^2)$.

Comment: This lemma is just to show that we can use different functions? If I specify functions and write $(S^1 \times D^2) \cup_{id_{S^1} \times id_{S^1}} (S^1 \times D^2) \cong (S^1 \cup_{id_{S^1}} S^1) \times (D^2 \cup_{id_{S^1}} D^2) \cong S^1 \times S^2$ - is it correctly written statement?